# Number of leaves in a tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If a tree has 5 vertices of degree 2, 3 vertices of degree 3, 4 vertices of degree 4, then how many leaves are there in that tree?

I know the tree has at least 12 vertices and so it must have at least 11 edges.  Also the number of leaves must be odd but I could not proceed further.

Answer (score 5):

If $k$ is the number of leaves then the total number of vertices in the tree is $12+k$ with $11+k$ edges and the sum of the degrees is $\sum\deg(v)=(5\times 2)+(3\times 3)+(4\times 4)+(k\times 1)=35+k$. Now by handshaking lemma,
$$35+k=2(11+k)\Rightarrow k=13.$$

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Note that the number of leaves will be independent of how the verticies of valency $2,3$ & $4$ are joined. We reckon $\color{red}{13}$.